# Go http Post Request does not show cookie in response

Tags: go, http, cookies

i am making a post request and trying to get the cookie from my response. in this cookie is the token from my login.

I tested the same request in Curl and Postman and got the cookie back.

```
func loginAndGetToken() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    postData := strings.NewReader("name=name&password=password&action=login")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost/index.php", postData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating request: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error executing request: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Reading the response body
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading response body: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

    fmt.Println("Status code:", resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println("Response Headers:", resp.Header)
    fmt.Println("Response Body:", bodyString)
    fmt.Println("Cookies:", resp.Cookies())
    fmt.Println("Cookies:", resp)

    cookies := resp.Cookies()
    
    if len(cookies) > 0 {
        authDetails.PHPPASSSAFE = cookies[0].Value
        fmt.Println("Cookie value:", authDetails.PHPPASSSAFE)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No cookie found in response header.")
    }
}
```

Status Code 200, and i also get Header Infos from the response but the cookies array is empty

```
Cookies: []
```

**Update:**
My Curl request is looking like this and i am getting a cookie back.

```
curl -bPOST -d "name=user&password=password&action=login" http://localhost/index.php 

 curl -i -X POST \
  http://localhost/index.php \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'name=name&password=password&action=login'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 21 Feb 2024 15:15:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
Set-Cookie: phpPassSafe= tokenValue; expires=Wed, 21-Feb-2024 15:45:38 GMT; Max-Age=1800
```

Comment: It is possible that the cookie is attributed with "http-only". Those Cookies are inaccessible. That is a measure the prevent malicious modification on client sides. So its possible that its the reason causing you the issue.

Comment: @pavleprica     
i checked that in the inspect tool in the frontend but the column http-only is blanc

Comment: @CeriseLimón this is the output of this line ````Response-Header: map[Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Tue, 20 Feb 2024 15:49:54 GMT] Server:[Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)] Vary:[Accept-Encoding] X-Powered-By:[PHP/7.4.33]]````
but i dont see ````Set-Cookie````

Comment: The server did not respond with a set cookie header.  There's insufficient information here to determine why that happened.

Comment: @CeriseLimón in postman i got a set-cookie back but not in my go application

Comment: Then your "Postman request" and your "Go request" are not the same and the server decided to not include the Set-Cookie header in the response to the "Go request". So: Fix your Request.

Comment: Some ways to get help:  edit the question to show what works,  ask for help about your PHP code (I assume it's yours because it's running locally).